# Execution behaviour of spring managed scheduler task during server start up

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a spring managed scheduler task configured in my web application. The serviceScheduledTask is configured to run in every 10 minutes. Will this scheduler task run at the time of server start up or will run only after 10 minutes of server startup?

```
  <bean id="serviceScheduledTask"
          class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorTask">
        <property name="delay" value="0"/>
        <property name="period" value="600000"/>
        <property name="runnable" ref="serviceManager"/>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flow goes like this

1. When Code is deployed in Server, `ScheduledExecutorTask` is registered and a timer starts. In your case 10 min.
2. On completion of 10 min. Task gets executed and again timer is reset to 10 Min.

Time used by `ScheduledExecutorTask` is System Time where your server is deployed

Answer (score -1):

delay - the delay before starting the task for the first time (ms)

So in your case, delay = 0, ScheduledExecutorTask will start immediately when server start.

And after 10m, it will execute again.

Comment: This isn't about the normal `ScheduledExecutorService` but about the Spring abstraction on it. You don't need a `ServletContextListener` for that.